# How would I get the value of this sum in terms of n

Tags: summation

How would i evaluate this sum as an nth term:

$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r!r$

Also is there any particular method for simplifying sums that have an nth term with a factorial in?

Comment: I don't think there's a closed form for this sum.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. One may notice that
$$
(r+1)!-r!=r\cdot r!
$$

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: so all of the factorials cancel out leaving just $(n+1)! - 1!$ which simplifies to $(n+1)! - 1$

Comment: @user6817585 Yes, it's a *telescoping sum*.